# How to stop Heroku Local without restarting Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, heroku, servlets, heroku-cli

I have my `index.jsp` running on `local:5000` and when I type CTRL+C in Powershell to stop the local app, I get a message saying "[Done] Killing all processes with signal SIGINT".

I then Receive another prompt to "Terminate batch job? [Y/N]" and I typed Y and hit enter. This stops any output showing in powershell but for some reason the index.jsp still works fine as if it's still being hosted on localhost:5000.

How do I stop heroku without closing my entire powershell terminal and restarting (which seems to work, but its a PITA)?

Comment: How do you start the webapp? What does your batch(?) file contain?

Comment: I start the web app by first running Maven (mvn package) and then running heroku local. I don't think I have a batch file.